# Java web Start application does not use JRE specified in jnlp file

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

## Environment:

### OS: Windows Vista version 6.0 (SP2)

Java versions installed (checked in Control Panel):

- jre1.6.0, Java Update 2,
- Java Update 3,
- Java Update 5,
- Java Update 31

(in C:/Program Files/Java related folders were found: jre1.6.0, jre1.6.0_02, jre1.6.0_03, jre1.6.0_05, jre6)

```
java -version response:
Java (TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b05)
```

### Problem:

According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html and http://webstartfaq.com/#49 I can specify the JRE version to run. I want to use JRE 1.6.0_31 (Java 1.6, update 31). To do that I need to set

```
j2se version="1.6.0_31+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"
```

in JNLP file. I did that but JRE version used by Java web start application is incorrect.

### Step to reproduce:

Start "C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/javaws.exe my_jnlp_file" with the setting mentioned

#### Expected result:

The process should start with: Java Web Start version 1.6.0_31 and JRE version 1.6.0_31.

#### Actual result:

The process starts with: Java Web Start version 1.6.0_31 and JRE version 1.6.0-oem-b104 Java HotSpot(TM) client.

I do not see any sense in that. Will be grateful for some ideas!

Comment: *"Will be grateful for some ideas!"* 1) Look over [Java Web Start - Runtime Versioning](http://pscode.org/jws/version.html). 2) Validate the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I tried to change jnlp file and start my application locally. But all the time it loaded new settings from the server. Once I changed the jnlp settings on the server side it started to work fine.